# Custom Visibility Modifiers in C++

Tags: c++

I was reading [Signals & Slots | Qt Core 5.4](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) and they had the following code snipped.

```
#include <QObject>

class Counter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Counter() { m_value = 0; }

    int value() const { return m_value; }

public slots:
    void setValue(int value);

signals:
    void valueChanged(int newValue);

private:
    int m_value;
};
```

I have seen `private`, `public`, and `protected` before but never anything like this.

- What is going on with the whole `public slots:` and `signals:` visibility modifiers (is this what they are called)?
- What do they mean and where in the standard do they talk about this?
- When can / should I use these in my own code?

Comment: Notice that the syntax highlighter misses them - they're not standard C++; hence not in the standard, and not coloured as keywords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`slots` `signals` just evaluate to empty strings or modifiers and they are defined implicitly by including `QObject.h`. These are just markers for the Qt `moc` (meta object compiler). `Q_OBJECT` is being expanded to some generic Qt-class interface.

The `moc` will generate code from your header and with these macros you provide extra information like 'these methods are slots' or 'this is going to be a Qt-ified class'

You should only use them in Qt-Projects and the case you develop a class which 'become' and deal with Qt objects. Examples are your own Qt-Widgets or any object that should be able to send/receive signals.

You won't find anything in the standard about these macros because they are not part of it. It's just an extension by the Qt-Framework and you will only be able to compile your classes when you include the appropriate Qt header files.

Comment: Right, they aren't standard c++.

Comment: How can i create my own modifiers like QT does?